# Is my passport considered damaged?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, passports

My passport is slightly broken as in pic, everything else is intact. Is it considered as damaged passport? My first passport was water damaged and this is second and if it is considered as damage, will it give a bad remark?

[image: photo of a passport]

Comment: Sorry, what's the damage here?  The biometric page is bent?

Comment: It’s kinda broken, just near the photo. As attached in pic. Thank you

Comment: You should be fine. This is a minor damage and I had a similar one on my Indian passport too. Ideal is to get the passport changed but practically, it will be accepted (as was mine). However, once, my black cover separated from the biometric page and I tried to travel. Air India took my passport at Mumbai for further inspection suspecting tampering. But later in around 30 min returned it to me and asked me to replace it as soon I reached New York.